# UITableViewAutomaticDimension changes multiple times

Tags: swift, uitableview, constraints

I have a project that uses iOS's default dynamic font. As so, I'm using `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` for the height. I'm doing everything programmatically, so I set the constraints for my custom cells.

### My Understanding of Constraints and `UITableViewCell`s

From what I can understand about constraints, is that when you apply them to the `superView`, the attributes that you set to be constrained will be forced to move based on the size of the `superView`. But if you set the constraints to the `contentView` of the `UITableViewCell`, then the attribute that you set the constraints to will force the `UITableViewCell` to change its height, width, ext.

### CustomTableViewCell

```
import SnapKit

lazy var loadingIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView = {
    let loadingIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .gray)
    loadingIndicator.sizeToFit()

    loadingIndicator.autoresizingMask = [UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleHeight]
    loadingIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true

    return loadingIndicator
}()

lazy var logoImageView: UIImageView = {
    let logoImageView = UIImageView()

    logoImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFit
    logoImageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

    logoImageView.clipsToBounds = true

    return logoImageView
}()

lazy var storeLabel: UILabel = {
    let storeLabel = UILabel()
    storeLabel.sizeToFit()

    storeLabel.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .footnote)
    storeLabel.adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory = true
    storeLabel.textColor = UIColor.lightGray

    return storeLabel
}()

lazy var priceLabel: UILabel = {
    let priceLabel = UILabel()
    priceLabel.sizeToFit()

    priceLabel.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .title1)
    priceLabel.adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory = true
    priceLabel.textColor = UIColor.black

    return priceLabel
}()

lazy private var stackView: UIStackView = {
    let stackView = UIStackView()
    stackView.sizeToFit()

    stackView.axis = UILayoutConstraintAxis.vertical
    stackView.alignment = UIStackViewAlignment.leading
    stackView.distribution = UIStackViewDistribution.fill
    stackView.spacing = 0

    return stackView
}()

lazy private var priceStackView: UIStackView = {
    let priceStackView = UIStackView()
    priceStackView.sizeToFit()

    priceStackView.axis = UILayoutConstraintAxis.horizontal
    priceStackView.alignment = UIStackViewAlignment.center
    priceStackView.distribution = UIStackViewDistribution.fill
    priceStackView.spacing = 0

    return priceStackView
}()

override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    super.draw(rect)

    let margins = contentView.layoutMarginsGuide

    contentView.addSubview(logoImageView)
    contentView.addSubview(stackView)

    stackView.addArrangedSubview(storeLabel)
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(priceStackView)

    priceStackView.addArrangedSubview(loadingIndicator)
    priceStackView.addArrangedSubview(priceLabel)

    logoImageView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.left.equalTo(layoutMarginsGuide).offset(layoutMargins.left * 0.5)
        make.centerY.height.equalTo(layoutMarginsGuide)
        make.width.equalTo(logoImageView.snp.height)
    }

    stackView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.left.equalTo(logoImageView.snp.right).offset(layoutMargins.left * 1.5)
        make.right.centerY.equalTo(margins)
        make.height.equalTo(margins).offset(-15)
    }
}
```

### Output

Everything should work perfectly fine, but I don't get the [desired height](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQ1uo.png).

[First](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAHdD.png) height, a second later the height changes to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHmGa.png), and the final desired height is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQ1uo.png). Am I setting the constraints wrong, or is this just a general iOS bug?

Comment: What is `priceStackView` vs `stackView`, are they vertical / horizontal, what `alignment` and `distribution`? Also, maybe include a screenshot of your view hierarchy in the different states.

Comment: Without this information, my hunch is that your `priceLabel` has `nil` value for `text` before loading the price, which makes `UILabel` have `0` of `intrinsicContentSize` height. If you put `title = ""` that could potentially solve your issue. Again without the view hierarchy I am not sure.

Comment: I added the variables such as `priceStackView` and `stackView`. And I included the screenshots of all the different states that it goes through. They're included as links.

Comment: If you don't plan on having multiline, setting height constraint for `logoImageView` should do the trick.

Comment: I encourage you to look into `SnapKit` if you're going to build layout with constraint programatically

Comment: Also I don't think you need to set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `false`, it should not change anything here.

Comment: I also tried to set the text for each of the `UILabel`s, but again, the output is still the same. I'm starting to think that this isn't a bug with my code, but an iOS or Xcode bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue turned out to be the function that I was declaring the constraints inside of. Instead of using the `draw(_ rect: CGRect)` override function, I needed to use the `init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?)` override function. The only reason I could think of for this is because the draw function happens after the init and after the margins have been set. So the constraints don't have time to update.

Here is the updated `draw(_ rect: CGRect)` to `init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?)` function:

```
override func init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    let margins = contentView.layoutMarginsGuide

    contentView.addSubview(logoImageView)
    contentView.addSubview(stackView)

    stackView.addArrangedSubview(storeLabel)
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(priceStackView)

    priceStackView.addArrangedSubview(loadingIndicator)
    priceStackView.addArrangedSubview(priceLabel)

    logoImageView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.left.equalTo(layoutMarginsGuide).offset(layoutMargins.left * 0.5)
        make.centerY.height.equalTo(layoutMarginsGuide)
        make.width.equalTo(logoImageView.snp.height)
    }

    stackView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.left.equalTo(logoImageView.snp.right).offset(layoutMargins.left * 1.5)
        make.right.centerY.equalTo(margins)
        make.height.equalTo(margins).offset(-15)
    }
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ContentView` must know it's size from subviews not vice versa

Remove `logoImageView` constraints and add these instead ,

```
logoImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.topAnchor).isActive = true

logoImageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

logoImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: layoutMargins.left * 0.5).isActive = true

logoImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100 ).isActive = true

logoImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100 ).isActive = true
```

Comment: try edit ??.... , Also try to comment other items constraints and test the image only to avoid conflicts